# Getting InvalidIndexError when trying to add indicators for an RNN LSTM model

Tags: pandas, numpy, keras

I am currently on a course about neural networks and am currently coding along. However, the tutorial does not include multivariate RNN LSTMs so I tried doing it myself. After researching, here is what I've implemented so far:

```
cols = 6
dataset_train = pd.read_csv('BPIdataset_train.csv')
training_set = dataset_train.iloc[:,2:cols].values
sc = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1), )
training_set_scaled = sc.fit_transform(training_set)
x_train = []
y_train = []
recurrence = 144
for i in range(recurrence, 988):
    x_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-recurrence:i, 0])
    y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i, 0])
x_train, y_train = np.array(x_train), np.array(y_train)
x_train
x_train = np.reshape(x_train, (x_train.shape[0], x_train.shape[1], 1))


regressor = Sequential()
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences=True, input_shape = (x_train.shape[1],1)))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(LSTM(units = 50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.2))
regressor.add(Dense(units = 1))
regressor.compile(optimizer= 'adam', loss = 'mean_squared_error', metrics=[RSquare()])
regressor.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=100, batch_size=32)
```

I was able to get results from here, however, I encountered InvalidIndexError upon applying the test set.

```
dataset_test = pd.read_csv('BPIdataset_test.csv')
real_soil_moisture = dataset_test.iloc[1:141,5:cols].values
real_soil_moisture
print(dataset_test.columns)
dataset_total = dataset_train.append(dataset_test)
inputs = dataset_total[len(dataset_total)-len(dataset_test)-144:, 2:cols].values

inputs =sc.transform(inputs)
x_test = []

for i in range(recurrence,  recurrence+len(dataset_test)):
    x_test.append(inputs[i-recurrence:i, 0:cols])
x_test= np.array(x_test)
x_test = np.reshape(x_test, (x_test.shape[0], x_test.shape[1], 1))
```

[image]